# Where can I find resources about X-Means Clustering?

Tags: clustering

Is there resources where I can find out more about this method, it was proposed by a client and there doesn't seem to be much on this.

Most of the searches seem to only turn up information about k-means.

Comment: Try searching with Google Scholar (!) or a similar academic search engine. Also, the Weka book might have something in the 3rd (latest) edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the original paper

```
    @INPROCEEDINGS{Pelleg00x-means:extending,
    author = {Dau Pelleg and Andrew Moore},
    title = {X-means: Extending K-means with Efficient Estimation of the Number of Clusters},
    booktitle = {In Proceedings of the 17th International Conf. on Machine Learning},
    year = {2000},
    pages = {727--734},
    publisher = {Morgan Kaufmann}
}
```

[Link to direct download](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dpelleg/download/xmeans.pdf)

Comment: Is there more than just this paper?